# iPhone: MPMoviePlayerController doesn't rotate on iOS 5.0

Tags: iphone, ios5, mpmovieplayercontroller

My code was working fine until I upgraded iPhone to iOS 5.0. The MPMoviePlayerViewController used to work fine but it doesn't work on iOS 5.0 so I have to use MPMoviePlayerController for iOs 5.0 and later versions. It works fine but MPMoviePlayerController doesn't rotate automatically like it used to do with MPMoviePlayerViewController.

Following is my code. Could anyone please suggest me how to make MPMoviePlayerController code rotate automatically?

```
 -(void)playVideo {
NSString *filePath = [appDelegate filePath:@"startup.mp4"]; 

if(!appDelegate.iOS5) {
    // This works perfectly till iOS 4 versions. Rotates automatically
    MPMoviePlayerViewController *videoController = [[[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL URLWithString:filePath]] autorelease];
    [self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:videoController];
} else {
    // This doesn't rotate automatically
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];
    MPMoviePlayerController* moviePlayer =  [[[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:url] autorelease];

    moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleDefault;
    moviePlayer.shouldAutoplay = YES;
    [self.view addSubview:moviePlayer.view];
    [moviePlayer setFullscreen:YES animated:YES];
}
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation
{
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try subclassing MPMoviePlayerController and forcing the orientation to portrait only.

```
- (BOOL) shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation {

      return (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight);
}
```

Not the best solution but I guess it should work.

Comment: There must be something else. I am wondering why it is rotating MPMoviePlayerViewController(iOS4.0 and earlier) but not MPMoviePlayerController(iOS5 and later)?

Comment: hi AppleDevelop,i am also facing the same prob,In my case i placed my viewController on a navigation controller and DidRotate is not getting called when the video is in full screen mode where as the method is getting called when in normal mode.If u had solved ur prob plz help me out...

Comment: I had to follow different approach mentioned at -http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9572640/ios-movie-player-view-doesnt-rotate It worked for me!

Comment: Yorxxx answer works if you have Tab based application and each tab returns true for shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation otherwise none of them auto rotates. You might want to look at "Why won't my UIViewController rotate  - https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1688/_index.html